# smarty php CMS error

Tags: php, smarty

hi when i open my site (made in smarty) i got this error plz resolve im very new in smarty

Smarty error: unable to read resource: "pagetemplate.tpl" in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/htdocs/includes/smarty/Smarty.class.php on line 1083

Warning: Smarty error: unable to read resource: "pagetemplate.tpl" in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/htdocs/includes/smarty/Smarty.class.php on line 1083

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Did you set your template directory to where the template file is located?

```
$smarty->template_dir = ...
```

Comment: So give Zed credit for the answer. 31 questions and not a single selected answer nor upvote.

Answer (score 2):

Smarty did obviously not find the "pagetemplate.tpl" file.

Two ideas :

- Does the file indeed exists ? (If your are under Linux, files names are case sensitive : "PageTemplate.tpl" and "pagetemplate.tpl" would not be the same file.
- Is smarty's [`$template_dir`](http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/api.variables.php#variable.template.dir) correctly set ? Does it point to the right directoy ? (same thing about case-sensitivity, btw)
- And a third : do you have read-access to that file / directory ?

While you're at it, you might also want to check the [`$compile_dir`](http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/variable.compile.dir.php) variable.

Comment: what is the path of the file where i can change

Answer (score 0):

There is a few things you might want to check:

- Did you properly configure Smarty's initial settings as such?

**CODE:**

```
$smarty->template_dir = '/path/to/templates_dir';
$smarty->compile_dir = '/path/to/compile_dir';
$smarty->cache_dir = '/path/to/cache_dir';
```

- Does `pagetemplate.tpl` exist within `$smarty->template_dir`?

Comment: what is the path of the file where i can change

Comment: **@vipinsahu:** modify the file where you create your Smarty instance to set those path.